# How can I convert a list of images from another directory into pytorch tensors

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch

I have a pandas dataframe that stores the names of the images I want to convert and a directory that contains all the images. I'll only need some of them so what would be the best practice for converting them? I wrote the code below to test if I can search the way I intended.

```
for file in os.walk(path):
    if file in images_to_convert["img_id"]:
        print("True")
```

I get

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Most people would probably use PIL (`Image.open()`) or openCV (`cv2.imread()`) to open the images, as they provide convenient libraries to convert images into numpy arrays. From there conversion to tensor is trivial